# How to detect if device's date isn't true? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

How can I check if the device's date isn't true with javascript?
(Like: if corrent date is 2016/6/16 and device date is 2016/6/15. Show alert).

Comment: with just client-stuff, you can't. JS is running INSIDE that client, and therefore will only ever see the dates that the client's clock is providing. garbage in-garbage out- you need to compare that client date/time against a known-good external source. of course, if something is GROSSLY wrong, like reporting 1972 when you know your code came into existence in 2016, you might have a small hint there that it's not quite right.

Comment: Even if you talk to a server you may still occur in issues with plain dates. Consider to get the UTC value of a date to avoid most timezone issues.

Comment: Ask a trusted server.

Comment: How can I talk to server?

Comment: see this website http://time.is it doesn't have any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tell if a device's clock is correct with 100% certainty. That said, you can use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) or [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to try to ask a trusted server for a datetime stamp and compare that with what the device reports. At minimum, there will be a margin of error largely involving network latency.

Anyway, something practical:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myCallback(json) {
    var internalNow = new Date();
    var externalNow = new Date(json.dateString);
    var msg = '';
    if(
         internalNow.getUTCFullYear() == externalNow.getUTCFullYear()
      && internalNow.getUTCMonth() == externalNow.getUTCMonth()
      && internalNow.getUTCDate() == externalNow.getUTCDate()
    ) {
      msg = 'Date matches.';
    }
    else {
      msg = 'Date DOES NOT match.';
    }
    alert(msg);
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

This relies on www.timeapi.org which doesn't support HTTPS. I'm not aware of a similar service that does. You might be better off setting up your own time service. It also doesn't check for normal, minor fluctuations so there's likely to be issues around midnight UTC.

Comment: No problem I want any javascript can do that even if it will ask another server. Is there a free server for that?

Comment: @ZiyadZadi updated

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: It would be much simpler to do `if (Math.abs(internalNow - externalNow) < someLimit)` where *someLimit* is the discrepancy you're prepared to accept, say ±6e4 for 1 minute. Testing date values has an arbitrary precision of anywhere from ±1ms to ±8.64e7ms depending on the time of day.